# Linear gradient angle is not returned by JS/jQuery when it is 180deg/top/to bottom

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, linear-gradients

I currently have some CSS that looks like this:

```
.crop-image {
     background-image:  linear-gradient(180deg, 
                                        rgba(34,34,34,1), 
                                        rgba(34,34,34,0)), 
                                        url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Test_card.png);
}
```

However when I try to access it via JavaScript, jQuery, or the dev tools in Chrome, I get:

```
     background-image:  linear-gradient(rgb(34,34,34),
                                        rgba(34,34,34,0)), 
                                        url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Test_card.png);
```

This is removing the direction (`180deg` or `to bottom` both get removed). Another issue is that it is changing the first `rgba` to `rgb`. Both work the same (no angle is the same as 180deg or top to bottom), but is causing parsing issues in JS.

And this is causing some problems with my JavaScript which adjusts the gradient dynamically, and means I will have to alter the JS if I change the CSS (i.e. write the JS to assume or check the first value to see if it's an angle or a color).

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bxLg4jzy/).

Other issues are that Chrome changes `rgba(x,x,x,1)` to `rgb(x,x,x)`, Firefox changes `rgba(x,x,x,0)` to `transparent`. (Both of which also cause parsing problems but are a little easier to work around).

Is there any way to consistently get linear-gradient components? Or to prevent browsers from changing my CSS?

Answer (score 3):

**Why does JS/jQuery not return the same value as provided in CSS?**

jQuery's `.css()` method does not return the specified value for any property. It returns the computed style of the element which is computed by the User Agent based on specification. This is equivalent to the `getComputedStyle` method in vanilla JS. The [resolved value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) that is returned by these need not be the same as the specified value. It is almost always<sup>*</sup> the [computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value) that is specified in specs.

From [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/): (emphasis is mine)

> Get the value of a computed style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element.
>
> Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different ***browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal***, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

<sup>* - why almost always is beyond the scope of this answer</sup>

---

**What is the computed value for color and gradient?**

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color): (used `background-color` as reference but the behavior is same for all color values)

> **Computed Value:** If the value is translucent, the computed value will be the rgba() corresponding one. ***If it isn't, it will be the rgb() corresponding one***.

I couldn't find any similar documentation for `linear-gradient` describing what is the computed value but we can assume that Chrome converts the specified value to its *simplest form* without altering the actual meaning of the gradient. Thus angle or orientation is getting stripped when it is default value.

---

**What are the solutions?**

So, at present there is no way to get the `rgba()` value when alpha is 1 using the `.getComputedStyle` or `.css()` (jQuery) methods. The following are your only options:

- Set the initial `background-image` value to a variable in JS and use it for any manipulations instead of getting the CSS value through JS (or better still, set the value directly via JS instead of CSS).

  ```js
  window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.querySelector(".crop-image");
    var initialBg = "linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(34, 34, 34, 1), rgba(34, 34, 34, 0)), url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Test_card.png)";
    el.style.backgroundImage = initialBg;
    document.querySelector('.output').textContent = initialBg;
  };
  ```

  ```css
  .crop-image {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="crop-image"></div>
  <div class="output"></div>
  ```
- Use values that are close (not exact) to 1 for alpha and 180 degree for the angles like mentioned in [**Adjit's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35734570/2606013).
- Or, parse the CSS stylesheet and get the `background-image` property's value. This can be done but it is very cumbersome and I won't recommend it.

---

**What is in pipeline?**

The [Level 4 Specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#propdef-color) indicate that the Computed Value would always be a `rgba()` color and so maybe once this is implemented all browsers would return a `rgba()` value irrespective of the alpha. But this is still in *draft* mode and so is subject to change (who knows, it may even get dropped).

[image]

---

**Any other points to consider?**

Firefox returning `rgba(34,34,34,0)` as `transparent` could be considered as a *bug* because [even as per MDN `transparent` maps only to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color). However, it is minor because alpha = 0 means the color is fully transparent.

> The transparent keyword maps to rgba(0,0,0,0).

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually believe that this is a bug. If you think about it what you are saying makes some sense.

`rgba(x,x,x,1)` is the same thing as just saying `rgb(x,x,x)` because by setting the opacity to 1, it means the element is fully opaque (not transparent).

`rgba(x,x,x,0)` is the same as setting the element to full transparency (making it invisible / transparent)

`180deg` gets removed because that is what the value is set to by default.

With all of these if you change the opacity value so it's not 0 or 1 and if you change `180deg` to anything other than 180 you will see these values show up.

https://jsfiddle.net/bxLg4jzy/2/

However, if you look in the developer tools CSS (not using any scripts) it will show up as the way you initially set it

Comment: You're right, it isn't technically a bug, (and yes, I was wrong about the dev tools, that was because of something else), but it is inconsistent with other angles and alpha colors and makes parsing logic in JS more convoluted since I have to anticipate how chrome/firefox will change my CSS (and as far as I know the only way to get the component gradients is to manual parse it).

Comment: One workaround, would be to use non-exact values (like 179, 0.01, 0.99), Otherwise, what exactly do you need your JS logic to be? Why not hard-code certain values into your JS and select them as needed?

Comment: The JS logic is just changing the gradient's second color alpha from 0 to 1 gradually as you scroll. I am not sure that I will always want the angle (or gradient color) to always be the same, but would prefer being able to just change that in the CSS without having to change the JS (or make it more complicated) every time I change the CSS. I will try using non-exact values for now though.

Comment: @Adjit: I've added a detailed answer explaining why browsers behave this way and have linked your answer within mine for the sake of completeness. I didn't want to repeat it because you've already mentioned it. Let me know if you are not OK with me adding that and I will have it removed :)